# how to add to different field values and store it in another field in elastic search python (elastic search field operation)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have written this elastic search query:

```
es.search(index=['ind1'],doc_type=['doc'])
```

I am getting following result:

```
{'_shards': {'failed': 0, 'skipped': 0, 'successful': 5, 'total': 5},
'hits': {'hits': [{'_id': '1327',
'_index': 'ind1',
'_score': 1.0,
'_source': {'val1': 1,
 'val2': None,
 'value1': 1327,
 'value2': 1531,
 'new_values': {'nv1': 1,
  'nv2': 0},
{'_id': '1349',
'_index': 'ind1',
'_score': 1.0,
'_source': {'val1': 2,
 'val2': 3,
 'value1': 1328,
 'value2': 1539,
 'new_values': {'nv1': 1,
  'nv2': 3}},.......
```

I want all the add val1, value1 and nv1 and store it in another field Let's call total. I want the result will be like:

```
{'_shards': {'failed': 0, 'skipped': 0, 'successful': 5, 'total': 5},
'hits': {'hits': [{'_id': '1327',
'_index': 'ind1',
'_score': 1.0,
'_source': {'val1': 1,
 'val2': None,
 'value1': 1327,
 'value2': 1531,
 'new_values': {'nv1': 1,
  'nv2': 0},
 'total1': 1329},
{'_id': '1349',
'_index': 'ind1',
'_score': 1.0,
'_source': {'val1': 2,
 'val2': 3,
 'value1': 1328,
 'value2': 1539,
 'new_values': {'nv1': 1,
  'nv2': 3},
  'total': 1331},.......
```

Comment: Which client library are you using?

Comment: Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

Comment: So you mean Python :-)

Comment: Yes. 
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use a script field in order to compute that value on the fly:

```
 es.search(index=['ind1'],doc_type=['doc'], body={
    '_source': true,
    'script_fields': {
      'total': {
        'script': {
          'source': 'doc.val1 + doc.value1 + doc.new_values.nv1'
        }
      }
    }
 })
```

The best way, though, would be to pre-compute that at index time and store the value in a new `total` field.

Comment: Instead of plus sign, If its negative sign, It gives only int value in return, How to make it float?
ex: 45/4/2 It should be 5.625, But it's giving only 5

Comment: Multiply or divide by 1.0 ;-)

Comment: Suppose val1 value is same for all, And I want to aggregate it by summing all fields for every val1 values.
what will be exact query for it.

Comment: that seems to be a different need than what you stated in your original question. The above does what you asked for, did it work?

Comment: It worked with slight changes. Can you up vote my question. Because this platform has blocked me from asking new questions.